# how to get fail user or password message in login form

Tags: java, sql

Hi i am trying to get a message says username or password is wrong when i type fail login info but the system crashes when i do that! it work perfect when i login in with right login info, but not when i type wrong user or password, the system will crash though.

```
private void btnLogInActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          



 if (projekt.Validering.textNotEmpty(tfUser) && Validering.textNotEmpty(tfPassword)){ 

   try 
     {  
     String name = tfUser.getText();  
     String password = new String(tfPassword.getPassword());  
     String allName = db.fetchSingle("SELECT PASSWORD FROM TEACHER where FORNAME = '"+name+"';");  
     String admin = db.fetchSingle("SELECT ADMINISTRATOR FROM TEACHER WHERE FORNAME ='"+name+"';");  



     if (allName.equals(password) && admin.equals("T"))  
    {  
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "you login as admin");  

        adminPagea = new adminPage(db); 
        a.setVisible(true);  
        this.dispose();  

    }  
    else if (allName.equals(password) && admin.equals("F")) 
    {  

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "you login as teacher");



        teacherPage ls = new teacherPage(db);  

         ls.setVisible(true);  

        this.dispose();  



    } else  

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "wrong user or password try again!");  



     } catch (InfException e) {

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "something went wrong!: " + e); 

}                                         
}
}
```

errors when the system crashes

```
enter code here
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at projekt.teacherPage.btnLoggInActionPerformed(teacherPage.java:171)
    at projekt.teacherPage.access$200(teacherPage.java:22)
    at projekt.teacherPage$3.actionPerformed(teacherPage.java:132)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 13 seconds)
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?  Please include it.

Comment: no error just the system crashes

Comment: @Inger Include `e.printStackTrace();` in the catch block and see the error stack on your IDE console.

Comment: @user75ponic still not working (crashes) :(

Comment: @Inger Include the error stack by editing the question.

Comment: @user75ponic I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @Inger Above `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "something went wrong!: " + e);` add `e.printStackTrace();` If there are errors, it will be shown on the IDE console. Copy and paste the error stack by editing your question.

Comment: I hope this code is not going to be used in a real production environment as it is *VERY* prone to SQL injections attacks. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Incorrectly_filtered_escape_characters

Comment: @user75ponic yes i did but it still crashes though..i will add errors

Comment: will `allName` have a value with an incorrect user?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav yes and i can login with no problems the only problem is when i type wrong user, then the system will crash.

Comment: @Inger the below shows the lines numbers where the problem lies. With these, it would easy for you to troubleshoot.  `at projekt.teacherPage.btnLoggInActionPerformed(teacherPage.java:171)
    at projekt.teacherPage.access$200(teacherPage.java:22)
    at projekt.teacherPage$3.actionPerformed(teacherPage.java:132)`

Comment: I think you're returning nulls, as the answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

you say this code works fine in case the username and password are correct. but there is some error in your variable name:

```
String namn;
```

and then you use it as name.

in the case its just a typo and original code uses correct variable name in that case **i think your problem is that you are invoking function on a null object**.

when you enter wrong username and password in that case the following lines :

```
String allName = db.fetchSingle("SELECT PASSWORD FROM TEACHER where FORNAME = '"+name+"';");  
     String admin = db.fetchSingle("SELECT ADMINISTRATOR FROM TEACHER WHERE FORNAME ='"+name+"';");
```

**return null values which are assigned to the allName and admin**.

after that you call some function on these variables in following lines :

```
if (allName.equals(password) && admin.equals("T"))
```

in this case allName is null and you are trying to invoke a function on a null object.

**try updating your code :**

```
private void btnLogInActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          



 if (projekt.Validering.textNotEmpty(tfUser) && Validering.textNotEmpty(tfPassword)){ 

   try 
     {  
     String name = tfUser.getText();  
     String password = new String(tfPassword.getPassword());  
     String allName = db.fetchSingle("SELECT PASSWORD FROM TEACHER where FORNAME = '"+name+"';");  
     String admin = db.fetchSingle("SELECT ADMINISTRATOR FROM TEACHER WHERE FORNAME ='"+name+"';");  


     if((allName!=null)&&(admin!=null))
     {

             if (allName.equals(password) && admin.equals("T"))  
             {  
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "you login as admin");  
                 adminPagea = new adminPage(db); 
                 a.setVisible(true);  
                 this.dispose();  
            }  
            else if (allName.equals(password) && admin.equals("F")) 
            {  
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "you login as teacher");
                 teacherPage ls = new teacherPage(db);  
                 ls.setVisible(true); 
                 this.dispose();  
             }
     }
     else  
     {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "wrong user or password try again!");  
     }     

     } 

     catch (InfException e)
      {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "something went wrong!: " + e); 

      }                                         
}
}
```

Comment: yes the code works fine because it is in Swedish and i change it to English so you can understand .. so yeah it works fine.